# Discord.py - add_roles on DM

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roles

Essentially, im trying to build a bot that gives a user a specific role when the user is sending a DM with a specific keyword to the bot as a DM. The Keyword stuff and everything is working perfectly. The server is parsed right, but I think I have made a mistake at some point when getting the role or adding the role. Here is the specific part of my code that is used for the role-ing:

```py
server = client.get_guild(<my server id here>)
role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Member")
await user.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
```

Comment: Are there some exception raised? Add try except to this code to catch them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `member` object not the `user` object as a `user` object is not linked with a guild.

```py
server = client.get_guild(server_id)
role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Member")
member = server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)
await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it to definetely retrieve the right user and server, but `add_roles` still is not working. I did not get an exact traceback, but there were no roles added. Maybe I do not retrieve the right role? Otherwise I cannot figure out why these problems occur

Comment: Excuse me, I now managed to raise the right exception and saw that the bot was just missing permissions on the server. Sorry to waste your time and thank you bot a lot for your very helpful answers. Merci Beacoup! :)

Answer (score 1):

User in DMs don't have roles, Member in a guild has roles, so you need to get member from that user ID for that server.

Also the add_roles method only takes in roles not User/Member object

```py
server = client.get_guild(<your server id here>)
role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Member")
member = server.get_member(user.id)
await member.add_roles(role)
```